# How does the returned views from React-Native app's render() transformed into native UI component?

Tags: view, react-native

I would like to know how the views returned from the `render()` method of an React-Native app transformed into native ones.

I have read some of the most important code in React-Native project, like `XReactInstanceManagerImpl`, `CatalystInstanceImpl`, and `UIManagerModule` etc. However, I cannot find any code which is used to transform the virtual DOM into the native view hierarchy.

Can someone give me some clue for this?